# Can you set partial transparency of an object in Access?

Tags: ms-access, transparency

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to set the transparency of an object in a MS Access form to anything other than yes or no? I was wondering if I could use setvalue for the object in question but I'm hitting a brick wall.

Thanks,
Ste

Comment: What kind of object?  label? Textbox? Combobox? Image/Picture? Button?

Comment: @donPablo. I have a text box and an image.